# $\tan^{-1} (-1) - 2\cos^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2}) + \sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

Find principal value of $\tan^{-1} (-1) - 2\cos^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2}) + \sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})$.How?

Comment: Found...! Now what...!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 1):

$$-\frac{\pi}{4}-2\cdot\frac{2\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{6}$$